react用にyarnでpackage.jsonを作成したい
yarnでpackage.jsonを作成する際にエラーが出る
実行したコマンド
yarn init -y

表示されたエラーメッセージ
yarn init v1.22.22
warning The yes flag has been set. This will automatically answer yes to all questions, which may have security implications.
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
error Could not open cafile: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mskba\OneDrive\ドキュメント\pure-react\Kaspersky.pem'
success Saved package.json
Done in 0.04s.

試したこと

yarn cache clear
⇒同じようにCould not open cafileのエラーが出る
npm uninstall -g yarn
⇒removed 1 package in 297ms
⇒その後yarn -vをすると1.22.22が表示されるため正しくアンインストールできていないのではないか
node.js(LTS版)を手動でインストール
Kasperskyの証明書の場所をWindowsのprogramDataのところにないか探してみたところ、Kasperskyのフォルダがないことが分かりました。

Kasperskyがこのエラーにかかかわっているのではないかと感じましたが、エラーの解消が前進しなかったため質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いいたします。
